Can I use a Qi Charging Stand with an 80% Charge Limit for iPhone to run on external power source limiting charging cycles?
I've recently set an 80% charge limit on my iPhone to help manage battery health. I'm considering leaving my phone on a Qi charging stand throughout the day. Would this approach be similarly effective to using a tool like AlDente Pro, which manages charging levels on MacBooks?
My main concern is whether the phone will continuously charge and discharge around the 80% mark, causing potential harm to the battery due to frequent cycling. Could this happen, or will the charging stand maintain the battery level effectively without repeatedly triggering charge cycles?
I purchased a nice charging stand and find it very convenient to just leave my phone there, keeping it always ready at 80% without going through full charge cycles, especially since I'm home all day. And I would hope this way I could limit charging cycles massively, like I do with my Mac on AlDente.

I found out with experimentation that the charger and the phone are cold when the phone is on 80% with the 80% limit standing on the charger so when the charger is a MagSafe charger the phone will run from the charger and the charging will not be happening for the battery as it will sit on 80% there so I would say it's not doing anything bad to the battery

The phone (and the computer both) prioritizes powering the device before the battery, so in the case of a fully charged (or charge limited) battery the power will flow directly to power the screen and processor.
There is no need to worry about excessive cycling in the scenario you describe.

That for sure applies for cable charging, but does it also apply for Qi charging? If so, it's safe to assume that letting it sit on a qi charge stand at 80% limit is the best that can be done for battery preservation?

There's always a chance it works differently, but there's no reason to believe it's any different. Furthermore, Apple itself has a feature ("StandBy") that encourages always-on while attached to a Qi charger.

I would use a physical cable if I had to ensure the best power delivery. Wireless charging can’t provide as fast a charge as cable so you are more likely to exceed the power budget and dip below 80%.
I think optimized charging is the best for me and 80% should be even more conservative (safer and more likely to prolong the months that battery can stay in service), especially if you deplete the charge in the battery entirely at least every 6 weeks to ensure it’s not always above 50% charge.

https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/

You will probably have the best success if you keep the phone as cool as possible, so consider low power mode if your wireless charge can’t keep up or it gets warm in use. You’re not going to wreck the phone doing both for a month. Why not run an experiment and report back in three months which setting keeps the phone the lowest temperature?
